# I'm far from perfect. Who Am I?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I am far from perfect

Though perfect is like me

I acted like an idiot

On live late night TV

You could say I am a cat

With stripes of orange and black

But I am more an angry bull

For flags make me attack

My first you've never heard before

My last is also rare

But it's the part that's perfect

(almost, not everywhere)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are...

> Vontaze Burfict, the Cincinnati Bengal player whose on-field antics caused his team to lose the AFC wild card game in the 2015 NFL playoffs.

Because,

I am far from perfect

> Burfict is known for causing issues on the field.  In addition, though he was considered a very good draft choice, his on- and off- field antics in college and poor performance at the combine, marked him lower in the eyes of teams, and he went undrafted.

Though perfect is like me

> last names rhymes with perfect

I acted like an idiot

> Happens almost every year.  He inevitably causes a fine-worthy penalty sometime during the season.

On live late night TV

> The Pittsburgh - Cincinatti playoff occurred at night on January 9th, 2016.

You could say I am a cat

With stripes of orange and black

> Cincinnati Bengals, named after Paul Brown's high school team

But I am more an angry bull

> See above concerning on- and off- field antics

For flags make me attack

> Seeing a yellow flag on the field seems to make him angrier and cause more issues on the field.

My first you've never heard before

> Vontaze is not really a common first name, at least in the U.S.

My last is also rare

> Burfict is also not a really common surname either.

But it's the part that's perfect

(almost, not everywhere)

> Again, last name rhymes with perfect.

Of course, this could also apply to

> Adam Jones (aka Pac-man), Burfict's teammate who caused an additional penalty after the Burfict penalty for pushing a ref on the field.

Comment: Got it! But try to explain just how each line matches up with your answer. I will accept it when you do that.

Comment: @RichardRoe.  There you go.

Comment: That's it. Now just to improve my riddling, was the rhyme too repetitive?

Comment: @RichardRoe.  Nope. I actually watched that travesty, so it was fairly easy for me at least.

Comment: I got the cincinatti Bengals connection, I was just lead down the wrong path of the panthers by the perfect references, (almost). Nice riddle.